# Mathematica Import and orphaned file

Tags: import, high-performance-clusters

I am having trouble with the orphaned files in the cluster.

I am using Mathematica in the supercomputer cluster for some reason. I am producing orphaned files, which means that the files are deleted before they are closed. I use Thinlinc to open and visualize the Mathematica, so I do not use scripts.

The only command that I use in Mathematica is something like

```
A = Import["file.h5",{"Data",10}];
```

Once used, I close the Mathematica application.

Could this make an orphaned file?
Some problems might be that I do not explicitly close after importing the file since I assumed that it would close automatically once I close the application.